# TFS PBI/Bug state - when all tasks are set to Done or Removed

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-workitem

Apologies if this has already been asked and answered.

I want to only allow a TFS user to change the state of a PBI/Bug when all tasks have been set to Done or Removed.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

By default we cannot achieve that.

However you can have a try with the extension [TFS Aggregator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tfsaggregatorteam.tfs-aggregator-web-service#) which is a plugin that is designed to handle this scenario.

There is a thread just has the same requirements submitted on GitHub with the discussion on using the [TFS Aggregator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tfsaggregatorteam.tfs-aggregator-web-service#) to achieve that, you can refer to it for details : [Update the state of a PBI (or any parent) to "Done" when all children get moved to "Done" or "Removed"](https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator/issues/215)

Related user voice here : [Automatic State Transition based on linked Work Item State](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/32044321-improve-hosted-build-agent-performance-with-build)

Comment: I'll give this a try. Thank you.